Cannot place math text (plotmath) in geom_table
The error

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
cannot coerce class ‘"expression"’ to a data.frame

occurs when creating a legend for geom_table():
# making table legend
legend_table_a488_old <- tibble(x = 2, y = 170,
              tb = list(data.frame( Parameter = c(expression(F[max]), 
                   expression(F[min]), expression(K[d])),
              Value = c("148.7", "172.7", "0.2298"))))

Not allowing the use of plotmath expressions in the data frame. Then a theme was made
# table theme
tabletheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(colhead =     
              list(fg_params=list(col="white"),
                   bg_params=list(fill="red")),
              core = list(bg_params=list(fill = "#FFCCCC", col = "green")))

and the table data was added to my plot

ggplot(data = a488_old_df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  ggtitle("SuBP 348C - Alexa 488 Fluorophore, trial 1") +
  xlab("Sucrose Concentration (mM)") + 
  ylab("Fluorescence at 526 nm") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) ((148.7- 172.7)/(1+ (0.2298/x) )) + (172.7)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.8, color = "red") +
  geom_table(data = legend_table_a488_old,   aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb),
           vjust = "top",
           table.theme = tabletheme)

and the plot successfully generates all included plot elements, but the geom_table() annotation displays the table text obviously without using plotmath (instead it is plain text). Is there a possible workaround for displaying math expressions inside of the geom_table() annotation? I have tried using the pkg latex2exp without any luck.

Instead of using expression use a character vector of plotmath expressions and set parse=TRUE in your table theme:
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpp)

legend_table_a488_old <- tibble(
  x = 2, y = 170,
  tb = list(data.frame(
    Parameter = c("F[max]", "F[min]", "K[d]"),
    Value = c("148.7", "172.7", "0.2298")
  ))
)

tabletheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
  colhead =
    list(
      fg_params = list(col = "white"),
      bg_params = list(fill = "red")
    ),
  core = list(
    bg_params = list(fill = "#FFCCCC", col = "green")
  ),
  parse = TRUE
)

ggplot() +
  ggtitle("SuBP 348C - Alexa 488 Fluorophore, trial 1") +
  xlab("Sucrose Concentration (mM)") +
  ylab("Fluorescence at 526 nm") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_table(
    data = legend_table_a488_old,
    aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb),
    vjust = "top",
    table.theme = tabletheme
  )


